# Get application's main window from current thread

Tags: c#, .net, windows, topmost

I'm writing a regular class library in .NET Framework (Windows). When someone is calling a certain method in that class library, I want to move the caller's main window (if any) on top of other application's windows (although not permanently).

At first I assumed I could use the Application class to get the main window (Application.Current.MainWindow) but the Application class seems not available...?

Is there a way to do what I want without resorting to native P/Invoke calls? If not - what can be done with P/Invoke when all I know is my current thread?

Comment: Generally, it's better for libraries to *not* try to deal with any UI concerns - raise an event and let the *caller* decide on the most appropriate action.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: In general, I agree with you. However, since there are already a number of (internal) applications using this library, I don't want to make that same change  in all of those applications.